# Change color of string gridview arrayDataProvider

Tags: php, yii2

I use `ArrayDataProvider`

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $data = order::getSome();


    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $data,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['order_customFields_delivery_method']
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],
    ]);
    return $this->render('index',['dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);
}
```

How can I change color of string in gridview depending on the conditions? Something like this^

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter', 'nullDisplay' => ''],
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'rowOptions' => function ($model)
        {
            if($model->order_customFields_delivery_method == 'eu-multi'){
                return ['class'=>'success'];
            }

        },
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'order_customFields_delivery_method',
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show approx. view how it should look like and what you currently have? Not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I have standart gridview whith white-grey strings. Code in `rowOptions` didnt work. I want when `order_customFields_delivery_method == 'eu-multi'` color of strin changed to green forexample.

Comment: What about your CSS file?

Comment: The code looks correct. Does the html produced include the class? If it does it may be your css rule/file as @EdvinTenovimas suggested.

Comment: your approach is coorect ...just try remove the space between function and ()

Comment: in css file `.grid-view td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}` when I add `background-color: red;` color changed for all strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'rowOptions' => function($data)
    {
        if($data['order_customFields_delivery_method'] == 'eu-multi'){
            return ['style' => 'background-color:#FFB6C1;'];
        }

    },
```